# Isotope, Masonry or neither?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Both [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) and [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/fluid.html) are impressive plugins. But I'm not sure if they are what I need in order to achieve this [effect](http://themes.rubenbristian.com/?theme=wowway) - where the images adjust so that they always fit perfectly across and there is no margin on either side. So [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/LTXRt/1/) what I have but I initially want the boxes to fill the container and then adjust in size as the container is reduced.

Which of these plugins will achieve that effect?

Comment: It appears that neither isotope nor masonry resize images.

Comment: I wasn't sure, glad I included neither in the question :) Any ideas what route would be the best to take?

Comment: For the record, I disagree that this wasn't a constructive question - it was a specific question about how a desired effect could be achieved. It was also researched and a Fiddle link is posted to illustrate. The answer wasn't intended to be an opinion but was a specific question about which of the plugins was capable of achieving the effect I had in mind.

Comment: Not sure why it was closed either, I would be interested in reproducing that effect too.

Comment: Likewise. This is most definitely *not* an unconstructive question. I came here exactly for this question, and am sad to find this was closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fluid layout, you use Isotope [this way](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html) and omit margins to butt up the elements right next to each other.

Comment: Sure, Isotope developed By David De Sandro is a very reliable tool, better than Windows 8 tiles, because the plugin puts you in control.